# Pausing a Youtube video when you play another video on the same page

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube iframe API to dynamically load a youtube video when the user clicks a video's thumbnail image. When a video is already playing, and a user starts playing another video, I want to pause the first video that is already playing.

I also want to load the next video after a video is done playing.

Here's my code:

```
loaded_video_array = new Array();

$("div.embed").live('click', function() {

    thumb.removeClass("play-button").addClass("pressed");

    add_embedded_player();

});

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0){

        $("div.pressed").parents("div.video").next().find("div.embed").click();

    }else if (event.data == 3){

        for (var i=0;i < loaded_video_array.length; i++){
             loaded_video_array[i].pauseVideo();
        }

        loaded_video_array.push(event.target);   
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a user dynamically loads a video, store it's variable/reference in an array.  Then, when starting a new video, just iterate through the array and pause each video.  If it's already paused, then no harm no foul.  It's not the best practice, but it will work.

Comment: how do I get the reference of the video? I've tried setting the `playerapiid` parameter and then calling `document.getElementById(apiid).pauseVideo()` but the error I get is that I'm calling the method on a null variable.

Comment: Can you post your code that plays the videos? I can help you from there.

Comment: OK I posted my code and followed your suggestions. It works except there's one big problem. I only can pause the videos in the array when the `event.data == 3` which is when the video is played from the beginning. If a user replays a video that has already been paused, it won't execute the pausing code for the other videos...